# Can I save a high resolution image of my plotly scatter plot?

Tags: python, plotly, plotly-python, scatter3d

Can I set a parameter for `plotly.graph_objs.go.Scatter3d` to either make the graph full screen or to set the save resolution higher? The current resolution that is being saved when using the built in save plot function is `983x525`. I would like to at least get it to 1080p.

```
trans = .6
trace1 = go.Scatter3d(
                    x = cluster0["PC1_3d"],
                    y = cluster0["PC2_3d"],
                    z = cluster0["PC3_3d"],
                    mode = "markers",
                    name = "Cluster 0",
                    marker = dict(color = f'rgba(255, 0, 0, {trans})'),
                    text = None)

trace2 = go.Scatter3d(
                    x = cluster1["PC1_3d"],
                    y = cluster1["PC2_3d"],
                    z = cluster1["PC3_3d"],
                    mode = "markers",
                    name = "Cluster 1",
                    marker = dict(color = f'rgba(0, 0, 204, {trans})'),
                    text = None)

trace3 = go.Scatter3d(
                    x = cluster2["PC1_3d"],
                    y = cluster2["PC2_3d"],
                    z = cluster2["PC3_3d"],
                    mode = "markers",
                    name = "Cluster 2",
                    marker = dict(color = f'rgba(0, 204, 0, {trans})'),
                    text = None)

trace4 = go.Scatter3d(
                    x = cluster3["PC1_3d"],
                    y = cluster3["PC2_3d"],
                    z = cluster3["PC3_3d"],
                    mode = "markers",
                    name = "Cluster 3",
                    marker = dict(color = f'rgba(255, 0, 255, {trans})'),
                    text = None)

trace5 = go.Scatter3d(
                    x = cluster4["PC1_3d"],
                    y = cluster4["PC2_3d"],
                    z = cluster4["PC3_3d"],
                    mode = "markers",
                    name = "Cluster 4",
                    marker = dict(color = f'rgba(255, 128, 0, {trans})'),
                    text = None)

data = [trace1, trace2, trace3, trace4, trace5]

title = "TEST"

layout = dict(title = title,
              xaxis= dict(title= 'PC1',ticklen= 5,zeroline= False),
              yaxis= dict(title= 'PC2',ticklen= 5,zeroline= False))
    
fig1 = go.Figure(data = data, layout = layout)
fig1.show()
```

Comment: You can use the `scale` parameter to increase the resolution of the image, e.g. `fig.write_image("fig_name.png", scale=5)`, see the [Plotly documentation](https://plotly.github.io/plotly.py-docs/generated/plotly.io.write_image.html) for more details.

Comment: @FlaviaGiammarino That increased the size but it is saving the default view. Can it save from a different angle?

Answer (score 14):

**Option 1:**
You can use this:

```
import plotly.io as pio
pio.write_image(fig, 'image.pdf',scale=6, width=1080, height=1080)
```

You can read [here](https://plotly.github.io/plotly.py-docs/generated/plotly.io.write_image.html), you will find that there are different formats, and also you can scale the image in pixels. I used `.png` format, and it is high resolution image.

**Option 2**:

```
config = {
  'toImageButtonOptions': {
    'format': 'png', # one of png, svg, jpeg, webp
    'filename': 'custom_image',
    'height': 500,
    'width': 700,
    'scale':6 # Multiply title/legend/axis/canvas sizes by this factor
  }
}


fig.show(config=config)
```

Click the `download` icon from the upper left of the figure and open the saved image and zoom it in, you will find it high-resolution image. You can also change the height, width, and scale(resolution) together.

Comment: So there no option to set the resolution to a specific value?

Comment: @Soran, you can play with scale which is almost resolution.

Comment: I don't like that. It is very inconvenient.

Comment: You have to modify the figure size and the scale together, is that was you mean? I rather have the option to download a higher resolution picture.

Comment: In my case, I didn't manipulate the size. It is only scale.